# Take the difference between two lists in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, compare, difference

I have two columns in my table with multiple values, and I want to get the values that are in one of the columns and not in the other column.

Its best described by an example:

```
including_ids | excluding_ids
123, 456      | 456, 789
```

I want to create a new column of all the `including_ids` that are not in the `excluding_ids`, so in the above example:

```
including_ids | excluding_ids | remaining_ids
123, 456      | 456, 789      | 123
```

If easier, I could also represent the values as lists or arrays or something like that.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: What should I better store it as, I'm free to store it as anything? It should be in 1 column

Comment: One value per row!

Comment: Any other solutions in case I need to store it on 1 row?

Comment: @Marjolein See my answer below. BTW, I think, it could be ok to use arrays in such contexts - especially given PostgreSQL's great support for them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use arrays for that:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (including_ids integer[], excluding_ids integer[]);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('{123,456}', '{456,789}');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('{1,2,3}', '{3,4,5}');
```

Then you can get the result you want like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT array_agg(i)
        FROM unnest(m.including_ids) AS arr(i)
        WHERE NOT ARRAY[i] <@ m.excluding_ids)
FROM mytable AS m;

 array_agg 
-----------
 {123}
 {1,2}
(2 rows)
```

But, as jarlh commented, using arrays or other composite data types is often a bad idea if you want to manipulate the values inside the database a lot. A more normalized data model is often a better idea: queries will become simpler, and the performance will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `intarray` extension:

```
create extension intarray;

SELECT including_ids - excluding_ids as remaining_ids
FROM mytable;

 remaining_ids 
───────────────
 {123}
 {1,2}
(2 rows)
```